# Elegant way to get a task for async code without running the task immediately

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have the following code that does what I want but I had to resort to using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in the middle of asynchronous code to get it. I am wondering if there is an elegant way to achieve this without resorting to such hacks.

This is a simplified version of the code I have.

```cs
public async Task<string[]> GetValues(int[] keys)
{
    List<int> keysNotYetActivelyRequested = null;
    // don't start the task at this point because the
    // keysNotYetActivelyRequested is not yet populated
    var taskToCreateWithoutStarting = new Task<Dictionary<int, string>>(
        () => GetValuesFromApi(keysNotYetActivelyRequested.ToArray())
        .GetAwaiter().GetResult() /*not the best idea*/);
    (var allTasksToAwait, keysNotYetActivelyRequested) = GetAllTasksToAwait(
        keys, taskToCreateWithoutStarting);

    if (keysNotYetActivelyRequested.Any())
    {
        // keysNotYetActivelyRequested will be empty when all keys
        // are already part of another active request
        taskToCreateWithoutStarting.Start(TaskScheduler.Current);
    }
    var allResults = await Task.WhenAll(allTasksToAwait);
    var theReturn = new string[keys.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach (var result in allResults)
        {
            if (result.TryGetValue(keys[i], out var value))
            {
                theReturn[i] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    if (keysNotYetActivelyRequested.Any())
    {
        taskToCreateWithoutStarting.Dispose();
    }
    return theReturn;
}

// all active requests indexed by the key, used to avoid generating
// multiple requests for the same key
private Dictionary<int, Task<Dictionary<int, string>>> _activeRequests = new();
private (HashSet<Task<Dictionary<int, string>>> allTasksToAwait,
    List<int> keysNotYetActivelyRequested) GetAllTasksToAwait(
    int[] keys, Task<Dictionary<int, string>> taskToCreateWithoutStarting)
{
    var keysNotYetActivelyRequested = new List<int>();
    // a HashSet because each task will have multiple keys hence _activeRequests
    // will have the same task multiple times
    var allTasksToAwait = new HashSet<Task<Dictionary<int, string>>>();

    // add cleanup to the task to remove the requested keys from _activeRequests
    // once it completes
    var taskWithCleanup = taskToCreateWithoutStarting.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        lock (_activeRequests)
        {
            foreach (var key in keysNotYetActivelyRequested)
            {
                _activeRequests.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    });
    lock (_activeRequests)
    {
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            // use CollectionsMarshal to avoid a lookup for the same key twice
            ref var refToTask = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(
                _activeRequests, key, out var exists);
            if (exists)
            {
                allTasksToAwait.Add(refToTask);
            }
            else
            {
                refToTask = taskToCreateWithoutStarting;
                allTasksToAwait.Add(taskToCreateWithoutStarting);
                keysNotYetActivelyRequested.Add(key);
            }
        }
    }
    return (allTasksToAwait, keysNotYetActivelyRequested);
}

// not the actual code
private async Task<Dictionary<int, string>> GetValuesFromApi(int[] keys)
{
    // request duration dependent on the number of keys
    await Task.Delay(keys.Length);
    return keys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => k.ToString());
}
```

And a test method:

```cs
[Test]
public void TestGetValues()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var allTasks = new Task[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var arrayofRandomInts = Enumerable.Repeat(random, random.Next(1, 100))
            .Select(r => r.Next(1, 100)).ToArray();
        allTasks[i] = GetValues(arrayofRandomInts);
    }
    Assert.DoesNotThrowAsync(() => Task.WhenAll(allTasks));
    Assert.That(_activeRequests.Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
}
```

Comment: IMHO delete `GetAllTasksToAwait` and rewrite your code without the circular dependency.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman
The production code is different and without the circular-ish dependency. 
Here I decided to experiment with the CollectionsMarshal instead of traversing the dictionary twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Task<Something> coldTask = new(() => GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

You can do it like this:

```
Task<Task<Something>> coldTaskTask = new(() => GetAsync());
Task<Something> proxyTask = coldTaskTask.Unwrap();
```

The nested task `coldTaskTask` is the task that you will later `Start` (or `RunSynchronously`).

The [unwrapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) task `proxyTask` is a proxy that represents both the invocation of the `GetAsync` method, as well as the completion of the `Task<Something>` that this method generates.

Answer (score 0):

You should [never use the task constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

If you want to refer to some code to execute later, use a delegate. Just like you would with synchronous code. The [delegate types for asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html) are slightly different, but they're still just delegates.

```
Func<Task<Dictionary<int, string>>> getValuesAsync = () => GetValuesFromApi(keysNotYetActivelyRequested.ToArray());

...

var result = await getValuesAsync();
```

Also, I strongly recommend [replacing `ContinueWith` with `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

All links are to my blog.

Comment: even if I don't much like your explanation ways, people must listen your advice, sir. +1

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire: How can I improve my explanations?

Comment: We a trifle time ago quarreled with this dichotomy between answering a question with ready-run code sharing and without it. You almost utterly prefer to go with the latter option, having no supplemental effect on rookie learners like me.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, my preferred teaching method is to lead students to learn for themselves. I have found that works best for the majority of people, but I understand that it may not be best for some. Sometimes I provide full code, sometimes not.